# All Notification is hidden when i clicked one of them

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

When push notification is clicked then push notification alert is hide from notification banner its okey but When i simply open the app not by clicking the notification, push notification auto clear, why? I haven't reset badge while launching my app.
And let's say that I have 5 notifications on my phone. If I open one of them all other notifications disappears. I want only the one clicked to disappear. Yes, I know this is default property of ios but i want to show the notification until user manually clicked or clear on it. I have handled like this

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print("this calls")
    print(userInfo)//json
    let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    let new = userInfo["news"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navVC") as? navViewController

    let state:UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
    if (state == UIApplicationState.Inactive || state == UIApplicationState.Background) {
        if  let _ = aps["alert"] as? String,let newsId = new["news_id"] as? Int {

            print(newsId)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(newsId, forKey: "K_Push_Id")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }

        if let category_name = new["category_name"]{
            print(category_name)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(category_name, forKey: "category_name")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("pushNotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's not just your app. Any app will make sure the notifications are gone once u open it. Or tap on one particular notification of that app as that app responsibly shows you all the notifications while you're **IN** that app. Makes sense though.

Comment: but i want to show the notification in notification center until user manually on it or clear it

Comment: The user have to enable them in notification center, elsewhere they won't show, even if YOU want ;)

Comment: I am talking about user enabled them in notification center case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done like this in appdelegate

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
         application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }
```

so every time if I open the app then its make `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to Zero and if `applicationIconBadgeNumber` is zero its clear all notification from notification center.